# SQL Server: Check quickly whether at least one table of a set of tables has been modified

Tags: sql-server

Given: Many tables, each with an indexed LastModified column which stores the date of the last modification for each row.

Desired: Information, whether any data of a table of the set has been changed (UPDATE) since a certain time, i.e. whether the value of the LastModified column is larger than a given reference time.

Current approach (shown just for 4 tables): If the following statement returns a non-zero value, the data of a table has been modified.

```
select (select case when exists(select ID from Table1 where LastModified >= CAST('2018-08-30T15:31:50' AS SMALLDATETIME)) then 1 else 0 end)
     + (select case when exists(select ID from Table2 where LastModified >= CAST('2018-08-30T15:31:55' AS SMALLDATETIME)) then 1 else 0 end)
     + (select case when exists(select ID from Table3 where LastModified >= CAST('2018-08-30T15:32:01' AS SMALLDATETIME)) then 1 else 0 end)
     + (select case when exists(select ID from Table4 where LastModified >= CAST('2018-08-30T15:31:49' AS SMALLDATETIME)) then 1 else 0 end)
```

Question: Is there another approach available for SQL Server with a better performance?

Execution plan for above approach for just 3 tables:

[image: Execution plan old approach just for 3 tables]

Comment: You could use UNION ALL instead of adding but it isn't going to change anything for performance. You are going to have to look at each table to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN modify_date > = '2018-08-30T15:31:50'
               THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END As Modified,
   Name As TableName 
FROM sys.tables
WHERE Name IN ('Table1', 'Table2','Tabl3','Table4')
```

Comment: Thanks! I will test it. Problem: The time to which the modify_date will be compared might be different for every table. I will update my question accordingly...

Comment: I see, I didn't see the time is different. Can you show us your Execution Plan?

Comment: Your solution (assuming a constant reference time) improved the performance by ca. 8%. I will post the execution plan now.

Comment: This is interesting but doesn't actually solve the OPs issue. You are looking at sys.tables to see when the table was last modified. The OP wants to look at columns in the table to see when the row was last modified.

Comment: @SeanLange I agree, however LastModified its not when the record was stored but when that associated table has been modified(Which you shouldn't do). Is this correct @Thomas853?

Comment: Just added the execution plans for 3 tables. In this case, the old approach is actually better. The 8% performance improvement was tested for about 20 tables.

Comment: Every row of each table has a LastModified value which stores when the row has been modified. Is this not a good idea?

Comment: @mvisser you have a great answer, but it doesn't answer the question being asked. The OP wants to look at the data, not the table structure.

Comment: @Thomas853 that is a fine thing to store in your data. This answer is looking at when the table structure was modified, it doesn't look at your data.

Comment: @Thomas853 Yes storing LastModifedDate's for rows is perfect. I thought you stored LastModified when a the table was modified. So dont use my solution.

Comment: @Thomas853 Also looking at your execution Plan. Your query seems fine.

Comment: Actually I am just interested whether a table has been modified since a given time or not. So maybe it is really better to look at modify_date of sys.tables, because I am not interested which entries have been modified (this will be done in a second step if required).

Comment: @Thomas853 - So you want to know if the table has been changed via ddl and you don't care about the data? This is getting more confusing the more details are coming out. Perhaps you should share your ENTIRE needs and we can help you.

Comment: @Sean: As I wrote in my question: Desired: Information, whether any table of the set has been changed since a certain time.

Comment: @Thomas853 I think you are confused about what you are asking. In your question you reference a column in your table. That indicates you are looking for when the data was modified with an UPDATE statement. But this answer is looking at when the table was changed. Meaning an ALTER TABLE statement. Those two things are not even close to the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, Sean! Yes, I want to know if the data of the table has been changed, not the table structure.

Comment: Ok, I was not aware that modify_date corresponds only to the table structure - thanks for clarification! I updated my question accordingly.